# Fail to install helm-diff

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have helm3 install from homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/helm).
I am going to install helm-diff (https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff).

This is my command:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
```

The result is:

```
Error: plugin already exists
```

I then:

```
helm plugin list
```

and returns

```
NAME    VERSION DESCRIPTION
```

Also I have tried:

```
helm plugin uninstall https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
```

and returns

```
Error: Plugin: https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff not found
```

What should I do to install this plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to ~/Library/helm/plugins to see if helm-diff exist. Then delete the directory. It should fix your problem.